# Images Not Appearing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am constructing a page with a thumbnail (beachthumb.jpg) that, with JavaScript and jQuery, should theoretically cause a full-size version of the image (beach.jpg) to appear in the space below the thumbnail. However, the full-size version isn't appearing and I cannot figure out what is causing that. Can anyone see what the problem might be?

Here's the HTML, CSS, and JavaScript (I'm positive the jQuery is correct, but if you want to see that as well, let me know and I'll add it).

Thank you in advance to anyone who can unravel this mystery!

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster">
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
<script src="js/index.js"></script>
<title>My Name</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="nav">
    <div class="header">
        <h1>My Name</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="links">
        <ul>
            <li class="travels">Travels</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="main">
    <div class="maincontent">
        <div class="thumbs">
            <img src="images/beachthumb.jpg" class="beach">
        </div>

        <div class="big">
            <img src="images/beach.jpg" class="beach">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
 </body>
```

CSS:

```
.nav {
margin:auto;
text-align: center;
}

.nav .header h1 {
font-family: 'Lobster', sans-serif;
color:#FF5A36;
font-size:60px;
}

.nav .links li {
display:inline;
list-style-type: none;
padding:10px;
font-size:25px;
font-family: 'Lobster', sans-serif;
font-size:30px;
color: #00A693;
}

.main {
background-image: url('images/lightcolumn.png');
width:100%;
height:100%;
position:absolute;
border-top: 2px #FF5A36 solid;
border-radius: 5px;
}

.thumbs {
display:none;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
text-align:center;
}

.thumbs img {
display:inline;
position:relative;
padding:10px;
}

.big img {
text-align:center;
display:none;
}

.big {
text-align:center;
}

.maincontent div {
display:none;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('.maincontent .thumbs .beach').click(function(){
    $('.maincontent .big img').hide();
    $('.maincontent .big .beach').fadeIn();
});

$("ul .travels").click(function() {
    $(".maincontent div").hide();
    $(".maincontent .thumbs").show();
});
});
```

Comment: Create a jsfiddle for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @sahbeewah said, you are hiding `div`, what is parent element and then, you are going to `fadeIn` child element. So edit jQuery code, where `thumbs` is clicked and change events.

```
$('.maincontent .big').hide();
$('.maincontent .big').fadeIn();
```

Now, in CSS you don't need to hide `.big img`, because its parent is already hidden.

```
.big img {
text-align:center;
}
```

Here is [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/debute/b4HsZ/).

EDIT:

Second variant, you can set selectors on `img` and `.beach`, but code will be litle changed.

```
$('.maincontent .thumbs .beach').click(function(){
    $('.maincontent .big .beach').hide();
    $('.maincontent .big .beach').fadeIn();
});

$("ul .travels").click(function() {
    $(".maincontent div img").hide();
    $(".maincontent .thumbs .beach").show();
});
```

And also, CSS need to be changed, firstly remove `disaply: none;` from `.thumbs` and then, disable display on `.maincontent div` children, except of `divs`.

```
.maincontent div img {
display:none;
}
```

Here is [second demo](http://jsfiddle.net/debute/b4HsZ/2/)

Comment: This is fantastic, debute. Of course the solution was simple, I just couldn't see the trees for the forest. Thank you so much for taking the time to look at my problem, it was driving me batty!

Answer (score 0):

The reason is this line:

```
$(".maincontent div").hide();
```

This causes the div with the class `big` to be hidden. So it doesn't matter that you faded in its child as the parent is hidden.

Comment: You're right! How did I not see that? Thank you for taking the time to look at my problem, I really appreciate it!